# facebook login email not come swift ( Isn't there any solution ? )

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3

hello i need some help i've been searching hours about this subject i tried a lot of thing but i couldn't do it.

Here is my code

```
let facebookReadPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]

    func getFBUserData() {
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
        self.getFBUserDataSecondStep()
    } else {
        FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: self.facebookReadPermissions, from: self) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
            } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
            } else {
                self.showLoadingAlert()
                let grantedPermissions = result?.grantedPermissions.map( {"\($0)"} )
                for permission in self.facebookReadPermissions {
                    if (grantedPermissions?.contains(permission))! {
                        print("permission: \(permission)")
                        // CONSOLE WRITING HERE LIKE THIS
                        // permission: public_profile
                        // permission: email
                    }
                }
                if (result?.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))! {
                    print("result is: \(result?.description ?? "nil")")
                    // result is: <FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult: 0x1c0441920> ( console )
                    self.getFBUserDataSecondStep()
                } else {
                    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    func getFBUserDataSecondStep(){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                if let dict = result as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    print(result)
                    // COMING WITH LIKE THIS

                    //"first_name" = Esn;
                    //id = 10156020817443470;
                    //"last_name" = "\U00c7ak\U0131ralar";
                    //name = "Esn Banu\U015f \U00c7ak\U0131ralar";

                    //--// Where is email ?
                    var email = ""
                    var firstName = ""
                    var lastName = ""
                    var facebookId = ""
                    var facebookToken = ""
                    if let controlEmail = dict["email"] {
                        email = controlEmail as! String
                    }
                    if let controlFirstName = dict["first_name"] {
                        firstName = controlFirstName as! String
                    }
                    if let controlLastName = dict["last_name"] {
                        lastName = controlLastName as! String
                    }
                    if let controlFacebookId = FBSDKAccessToken.current().userID {
                        facebookId = controlFacebookId
                    }
                    if let controlFacebookToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString {
                        facebookToken = controlFacebookToken
                    }
                        loginWithFacebook(email: email, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, facebookId: facebookId, accessToken: facebookToken, finishedClosured: { (state) in
                            if state {
                                let mainPage = self.mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
                                self.removeLoadingAlert()
                                self.passPage(page: mainPage)
                                return
                            }
                            self.removeLoadingAlert()
                            self.alert(message: "Giris Basarisiz")
                            return
                        })
                }
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
}
```

i need go get email of person to register user to my application. But email doesn't come whatever i tried. How can i fix this issue  and also if i try with my personel account its ok no problem but another user it can be problem.

Comment: Maybe the user didn't grant email permission? Maybe they don't have a verified email?

Comment: i tried this a lot of user i think it can not possible

Comment: and also this app that i trying to write finished in android and same user tried it in android result is succesfull

Answer (score 3):

```
    Note : This is in swift 4.0

    //giving permission
func getpermission(){
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
     //   fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web

        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if (error == nil){
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
                if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                    if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                    {
                        self.getFBUserData()
                        fbLoginManager.logOut()

                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
// Get all details from here
 func getFBUserData(){
        var fbId : String = ""
        var fbEmail : String = ""
        var fbName : String = ""
        var fbPickUrl : String = ""

        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    //everything works print the user data
                    print("Result111:\(String(describing: result)) "as Any)
                }
                let dict = result as! NSDictionary
                print("FB Email1st:\(dict)")

                fbId = dict["id"] as! String
                fbName = dict["name"] as! String
                fbEmail = dict["email"] as! String
 //get user picture url from dictionary
fbPickUrl = (((dict["picture"] as? [String: Any])?["data"] as? [String:Any])?["url"] as? String)!

print("FB ID: \(fbId)\n FB Email:\(fbEmail) \n FbName:\(fbName) \n FBProfileUrl:\(fbPickUrl)\n")


            })
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["user_about_me", "email" , "user_birthday","user_hometown"], from: self) { (loginResult, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                self.showalert(strMessage: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            }
            else
            {
                if loginResult?.grantedPermissions == nil
                {
                    self.showalert(strMessage: "Login Permissions not granted")
                    return
                }

                if (loginResult?.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))!
                {

                if (loginResult?.grantedPermissions.contains("user_birthday"))!
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                }
                else
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
    func getFBUserData()
    {



        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,cover,picture.type(large),gender,birthday,hometown", parameters: nil).start(completionHandler: { (connection , result , error ) in

            if(error == nil){



                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let dictionary = result as! NSDictionary

                    print(dictionary)
                    print("Name : \(dictionary.value(forKey: "name")!)")
                    print("FB ID : \(dictionary.value(forKey: "id")!)")
                    self.FaceBookID = dictionary.value(forKey: "id") as? String
 }

            }else{

                self.showalert(strMessage: "Somthig Went Wrong..!")
            }
        })
```

Comment: email doesn't come :(

Comment: facebook id and display name i had set it

Comment: CFBundleURLTypes what is it and what should i write ?

Comment: i check this its okay no problem cfbundleurltypes has already set it

Comment: "first_name" = Esn;
    gender = female;
    id = 10156022270488470;
    "last_name" = "\U00c7ak\U0131ralar";
    name = "Esn Banu\U015f \U00c7ak\U0131ralar";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/23231443_10156018012633470_3214814333059867676_n.jpg?oh=0db57fd0d54e4871847c55443697ba68&oe=5A642136";
        };
    }; its coming like this